# Getting an error in xamarin forms while inserting data: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: cancel'

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

Im trying a singUp page in xamarin for a project and in the method to insert the new user it appers to be an error. I tried to use addWithValue() command and Add(), and other methods but it always gives me this error "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: cancel'". My SingUpPage.xaml.cscode look like this:

```
async private void Guardar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsuario.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtContraseña.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCorreo.Text))
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(PaginaPrincipal.conexion);
        try
        {

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                string sql = "INSERT INTO users(Nombre_Usuario,Contra,Correo,Telefono) VALUES(@Nombre_Usuario,@Contra,@Correo,@Telefono)";

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con)) {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre_Usuario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtUsuario;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contra", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = txtContraseña.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Correo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = txtCorreo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefono", MySqlDbType.Int32, 10).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefono.Text);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result < 0) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data to DB");
                    }

                    await DisplayAlert("Exito", "Se añadio tu usuario", "Ok");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Paso esto: ", Convert.ToString(ex), "");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Required", "Los campos de Usuario, Contraseña y Correo son necesarios", "OK");
    }

}
```

My SingUpPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Saansa.Views.SingUpPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="4">
            <Entry x:Name="txtUsuario" Placeholder="Usuario" FontSize="Large" Margin="20,50,20,10"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtContraseña" Placeholder="Contraseña" FontSize="Large" Margin="20,50,20,10"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtCorreo" Placeholder="Correo"  FontSize="Large" Margin="20,50,20,10"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtTelefono" Placeholder="Telefono" FontSize="Large" Margin="20,50,20,10"/>
            <Button x:Name="Guardar" Text="Registrar" FontSize="Large" Padding="4" Margin="20,50,20,10" Clicked="Guardar_Clicked"
                    BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="20"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The database that i am using is Mysql and the columns of my table user are:

```
idUsers -> Type: int(11) PK NotNull AutoIncrement.
Nombre_Usuario -> Type:varchar(45) NotNull.
Contra -> Type:varchar(45) NotNull.
Correo -> Type:varchar(45) NotNull.
Telefono -> Type:int(11) NotNull.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide the exception stack trace it would make easier to help.

I guess the problem is happening in the following line because you need to provide a text for the alert cancel button:

`await DisplayAlert("Paso esto: ", Convert.ToString(ex), "");`

Try to give it a value ex:

`await DisplayAlert("Paso esto: ", Convert.ToString(ex), "test");`

Comment: That help to know that the ip in the server was not added, but know I get the following error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Parameter type Entry (DbType: String) not currently supported. Value: Xamarin.Forms.Entry'.

Comment: You forgot the .Text in the end of the following line: cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre_Usuario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtUsuario;
It must be txtUsuario.Text